# HTML dropdown menu has many <li menu items which causes it to wrap

Tags: html, css

The problem lies when adding to many menu items to fit on one line, it doesn't warp left to right on the second line in the menu. The result I'm looking for is for as the menu grows, the second line in the menu will start on the left as the first menu line does. Any help would be awesome. Note: We are not using any JS in this solution.

```css
li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  /* White color */
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<li style="float:left" class="dropdown"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">MENU ITEM # 1</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content"> <a href="" target="_blank" title="This is the test.">  &nbsp; menu item</a> </div>
</li>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a smal example of the problem and also an image of what you really want. This will make it easier for us to help you

Comment: /************************ HTML *************************************************************************/


  <li style="float:left" class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">MENU ITEM # 1</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="" target="_blank" title="This is the test.">  &nbsp; menu item</a>
        </div>
  </li>

Comment: li a, .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;

}


li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;

}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;    /* White color  */
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

Comment: @WXCUNIVERSAL Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow ! Please use the code snippet feature instead of posting your code in comments. Can you edit the snippet in your question to show us a complete version of your menu ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS:

```
#menu > ul { 
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#menu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 -3px 0 0;
}
```

`float: none` is needed to override the rule  `#menu li { float: left; }`, which causes the parent `ul`'s `white-space: nowrap` rule to be ignored.

`display: inline-block` produces an inline layout for the list items, but still allows them to be treated like block elements with respect to sizing and positioning.

The negative `margin-right` is needed to override the default conversion of a line break in the HTML source to a single space; without it, your top-level menu items will have spaces between them.

Comment: When i do this it over-rights a button fixed on the right side of the menu. :(

Comment: i remove the float left in the html section

Comment: Wow, i changed white-space: nowrap; --> white-space: wrap; it is now showing correctly. Thank you so much